# How to display or use custom field in KnowledgeArticle listing at Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, knowledge, articles

I am using the `knowledge:articleList` standard component like this:

```
<knowledge:articleList articleVar="article" 
                       pageNumber="{!currentPageNumber}" 
                       hasMoreVar="false" 
                       pageSize="3">

<apex:outputText value="{articleVar.title}"/>
```

We can display standard field.

But how do I display a custom field?

Comment: you should accept your own answer on this question, so the community user doesn't bump it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `apex tag` like `apex:repeat` can be used with the help of SOQL/SOSL to list Knowledge article of an organization with its `custom field`.

The other way to display article is just use SOQL/SOSL and show them on vf page using apex tags instead of standard `<knowledge:articleList />` component.

eg: how to do SOQL/SOSL on articles:

//Apex class code

```
String dataCategoryFilter = ' WITH DATA CATEGORY Country__c ABOVE_OR_BELOW States__c';
List < ArticleName__kav > lstSKAV = new List < ArticleName__kav > ();

//SOQL
String searchquery = 'FIND \'' + searchString + '*\'IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING' +
                            ' ArticleName__kav(Id, title, Summary ,customField1__c, customField2__c  where' +
                            ' PublishStatus =\'online\' and Language = \'en_US\') ' + dataCategoryFilter;
    lstSKAV = search.query(searchquery)[0];
}

//SOSL
String qryString = 'SELECT Id, title, Summary, customField1__c, customField2__c FROM ' +
                            'ArticleName__kav WHERE (PublishStatus = \'online\' and Language = \'en_US\') ' + dataCategoryFilter + ' Order By Title ';
lstSKAV = Database.query(qryString);
```

//Apex page code

```
< apex: repeat value = "{!lstKAV}" var = "article" >
      < div class = "articleBox" >
        < b >< apex: outputLink target = "_blank" value = "/{!article.Id}" > {!article.title}< /apex:outputLink></b >
          < br / >
                < div class = "textEllpisis" >
                    < apex: outputText value = "{!article.customField1__c}" escape = "false" / >
                  < /div> 
             < /div > 
 < /apex:repeat>
```